# What is the precise format of the live audio stream out of Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-connect, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

Amazon Connect [docs indicate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/access-media-stream-data.html) that the live audio stream (routed over Kinesis Video Streams) is 16-bit signed PCM Mono format.  Is that audio data sampled at 8 kHz, or some other rate?

Answer (score 0):

16-bit signed linear PCM, mono channel, 8kHz sampling rate.